# I can't find the correct XPath expression to send the Username and Password Keys to the Instragram Website by selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver, xpath, selenium-chromedriver

I want to send automate keys "Username" and "Password" to instagram.com, where I can't locate the correct Xpath expression of "Username" and "Password" to send the "Keys." I got an Xpath location error when I executed the code. For privacy purpose, I do not write the Username and Password.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep

class App:
    def __init__(self, username='#', password='#', target_username ='#',
                 path='C:/Users/ameni/Desktop/instaphoto'):
        self.username = username
        self.password = password
        self.target_username = target_username
        self.path = path
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:/chromedriver/chromedriver.exe')
        self.main_url = 'https://www.instagram.com/accounts/emailsignup'
        self.driver.get(self.main_url)
        sleep(3)

        self.log_in()

        sleep(3)
        self.driver.close()

    def log_in(self):
        login_button = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//p[@class='izU2O ']/a[@href]")
        login_button.click()
        username_input = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@aria-label='Phone number, username, or email']")
        username_input.send_keys(self.username)
        password_input = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@aria-label='Password']")
        password_input.send_keys(self.password)
        input('Stop for Now')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = App()
```

Answer (score 0):

The `username` and `password` `input` tags have `name` attribute. Use the same to locate them.

Was able to send text with these lines.

```
login_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//p[@class='izU2O ']/a[@href]")
login_button.click()

username_input = driver.find_element_by_name("username")
username_input.send_keys("Sample Text")

password_input = driver.find_element_by_name("password")
password_input.send_keys("SampleText")
```